# Textbox formatting to Currency C#.Net

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

I can't find an answer that suits what I need. So I figured I could ask you guys for help.

I have a textbox that I want to show a currency value of `$0.00` or whatever value they type ex: `$1,331.13`. I want it to change the format on the tab index event or is it done some other way in a property setting?

What should i put in the put in the event? I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
string.Format("{0:c}", txtPaymentOwed.Text);
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help suggested would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is related with the type of object you pass to String.Format

```
var s1 = string.Format("{0:c}", 3); //$3.00
var s2 = string.Format("{0:c}", "3"); //3
```

try with

```
var s = string.Format("{0:c}", Decimal.Parse(txtPaymentOwed.Text));
```

Comment: I suspect the OP will want to re-assign the result to txtPaymentOwed.Text, not to a new local variable.

Comment: @codesparkle Possible. Does this change anything in my answer (other that replacing `s`s with `txtPaymentOwed.Text` )?

Comment: the left hand side of your assignment. But it's obvious enough without editing, I guess.

Comment: Ok what event do i put it in?

Comment: Nvm I figured it out I added it to focus leave event.

Comment: That worked. Thanks, I been scratching my head and searching for a while trying to figure it out.

Comment: While you are there to help how do i validate the textbox to see if the value is 0 or not?

Comment: `While you are there to help` Yes we are here as your *personal assistant*. Ask whatever you want as follow up questions.